# For a real valued function $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is in $L_2$, show that $f(x+ε,y+ε) → f(x,y)$ in $L_2$ when $ε → 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

For a real valued function $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is in $L_2$, show that $f(x+ε,y+ε) → f(x,y)$ in $L_2$ when $ε → 0.$

Not sure how to go about this problem.  I tried Fubini.  But that didn't seem to work well.  I tried doing t straight from the definition.  It seems the point is that it epsilon is changing the $x$ and $y$ coordinate at the same speed.

Comment: Have you tried dominated convergence? [The same speed isn't really an issue at all.]

Comment: Yea.  What could you dominate it by?

Comment: Oh I see you can use the alternative version where you dominate each of the $f_n$ individually by $g_n$ and then show that you can bring the limit in for the $g_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Approximate $f$ in $L^2$ by a sequence $f_n$ of smooth compactly supported functions. Take a $\delta>0$. For sufficiently large $n$, one has $||f-f_n||<\delta$ and $||T_\epsilon f-T_\epsilon f_n||<\delta$ for all $\epsilon$, where $T_\epsilon g(x,y)=g(x+\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$. Fix such an $n$ and take $\epsilon$ small enough that $||f_n-T_\epsilon f_n||<\delta$. Then $||f-T_\epsilon f||<3\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. For $f \in C_c(\mathbb R^2)$ the property follows by using uniform continuity of $f$ and dominated convergence (note that $f$ is bounded on its compact support). Now use that $C_c(\mathbb R^2)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$.